# RewriteRule: Making an exception - remove one argument

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, flags

I'm sorry for this "bad" title, I'll try to explain it:

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mythbusters/tsp/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# RewriteRule ^album/(.+)$ index.php?url=album/show/$1
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The last line of this file is working perfectly. It allows to rewrite my URL from *_ROOT_/index.php?url=album/index* to *_ROOT_/album/index* (I'm using this to work with those parameters and to create beautiful URL's.

Although, there's one exception I want to make:

The out-commented line in my .htaccess file is one of my uncountable tries to rewrite a specific URL.

With the last line of my .htaccess file, the working URL looks like this:

*_ROOT_/album/show/name_of_album*
which is the same as
*_ROOT_/index.php?url=album/show/name_of_album*

Now, I want to remove the "show" part of this URL, I tried to to it with

```
# RewriteRule ^album/(.+)$ index.php?url=album/show/$1
```

But using this, every other path in my site changes which causes the CSS files fail loading (just pure HTML, no styles).

Are there some missing flags or even some wrong regex in this file?

Thanks for your help.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mythbusters/tsp/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^album/(.+)$ index.php?url=album/show/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**For css/js/image issue:**  use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

You can also try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Unbelieveable, it actually works! Also the css/js files are loading without any problems! (They have been included with absolute paths ;))

@anubhava: could you please explain the problem my .htaccess file was causing? I noticed the additional line `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` and the flags `[QSA,L]`. I do understand what the flags mean/do, but what does the additional line mean?

Comment: ²nd rule is just saying that skip all rules for files or directories. L is for last rule in current cycle and QSA is for query string append.

Comment: If it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.